# How do I read bridge entities in ERDs?

Tags: entity-framework, erd

First time posting here as I was told to seek help from this community if I was ever stuck!!

I was recently introduced to databases this semester and I have a hard time grasping the bridge entity that is meant to erase the many-to-many relationships.

The classic example would be the relationship between STUDENT and CLASS; 
where STUDENT can be in many CLASSES and a CLASS can have many STUDENTS.
The M-M relationship is fixed by introducing the ENROLL entity. Here we would read: a STUDENT can ENROLL in many CLASSES, and a CLASS may have many STUDENTS ENROLLED in it, however each STUDENT can be ENROLLED in a CLASS only once.

In my case, I tried to fix a M-M relationship issue between PRODUCT and RAW MATERIAL for a pharmaceutical company by introducing an INGREDIENT entity, which looks like this:

RAW MATERIAL 1----M INGREDIENT M----1 PRODUCT

I am not sure if the bridge works out because I have trouble interpreting it like the STUDENT-CLASS example above.

How would you interpret this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question is rather broad. You'll get better responses when you show code, for example the DDL of the tables and/or the Entity Framework classes. Also, try to explain by code what you mean by *I have trouble interpreting (...)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of "bridge" or "associative" entities came from network data modeling and was a way of handling many-to-many binary as well as ternary and higher relationships. Network data modeling is a simple physical data model based on representing entities as records and relationships as references/pointers.

Since the 1970s, the relational model of data has been developed which uses relations (tables) to record relationships between sets of values (which represent business entities, measurements and labels), allowing for the direct representation of many-to-many relationships and ternary and higher relationships.

The entity-relationship model was an attempt to provide more conceptual structure on top of the relational model, by distinguishing entity relations from relationship relations.

My point with the history is that in modern data modeling, we no longer resolve or erase many-to-many (or ternary or higher) relationships (unless you're using an object-relational mapper or framework based on the network data model). Tables with composite keys, consisting of two or more entity keys, directly represent relationships, and allow us to handle attributes on relationships as well, another feature missing from network data modeling.

In your case, it may be useful to add a `Quantity` attribute on your `Ingredient` relationship. The interpretation here is that `Raw material` refers to a type of material rather than a specific piece or selection of raw material. Students have identity, raw materials generally don't.

Note that pharmaceutical companies may well track specific batches of raw materials.